# Issue Capturing Global (Session 0) OutputDebugString messages via Win32 API?

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, outputdebugstring

I am currently working on a simple application to capture OutputDebugString messages  (similar to [Windows Sysinternals DbgView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647) or [DBMon.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/trace/DbMonNET.aspx)). Everything is working as expected when accessing OutputDebugString messages from the Local session (i.e., Local\DBWIN_BUFFER_READY, Local\DBWIN_DATA_READY and Local\DBWIN_BUFFER).

However, when I attempt to access any output from Session 0 (i.e., Global\DBWIN_BUFFER_READY, etc) I receive no output. Based on the behaviour of DbgView, I am operating on the assumption that the application must be run with some level of Administrative privileges. I am thinking I am configuring the SecurityDescriptor incorrectly, or I am missing something completely to access Global OutputDebugString messages (read as... I am now somewhat lost on the matter).

I have highlighted snippets of code below, but the full source may be found on [CodePlex](http://harvester.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/61230ec47f5d)

Any help or insight on the matter would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

**Security Descriptor Configuration**

I have tried a few different configurations, but the committed code currently looks as follows.

```
[DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern Boolean InitializeSecurityDescriptor(ref SecurityDescriptor sd, UInt32 dwRevision);

[DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern Boolean SetSecurityDescriptorDacl(ref SecurityDescriptor sd, Boolean daclPresent, IntPtr dacl, Boolean daclDefaulted);

public SecurityDescriptor InitializeSecurityDescriptor()
{
  const Int32 securityDescriptorRevision = 1;
  var securityDescriptor = new SecurityDescriptor();

  // Initialize the security descriptor.
  if (!InitializeSecurityDescriptor(ref securityDescriptor, securityDescriptorRevision))
    throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());

  // Set information in a discretionary access control list
  if (!SetSecurityDescriptorDacl(ref securityDescriptor, true, IntPtr.Zero, false))
    throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());

  return securityDescriptor;
}
```

This code is ultimately called in the setup of my DbWinMessageSource class as you would expect...

```
_windowsApi.Advanced.InitializeSecurityDescriptor();
```

**SecurityAttributes and Events**

The code currently committed on CodePlex is using the Local\** prefix, but the only difference should be that Local\** is replaced with Global\** as far as I understand it? However this does not seem to capture the output as expected. Again, the relevant code snippet...

```
  public const Int32 ErrorAlreadyExists = 183;

  [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
  private static extern IntPtr CreateEvent(ref SecurityAttributes sa, Boolean bManualReset, Boolean bInitialState, String lpName);

  public Handle CreateLocalEvent(ref SecurityAttributes securityAttributes, String objectName)
    {
      Verify.NotWhitespace(objectName);
      return CreateEvent(ref securityAttributes, "Local", objectName);
    }

    public Handle CreateGlobalEvent(ref SecurityAttributes securityAttributes, String objectName)
    {
      Verify.NotWhitespace(objectName);
      return CreateEvent(ref securityAttributes, "Global", objectName);
    }

    private static Handle CreateEvent(ref SecurityAttributes securityAttributes, String objectNamePrefix, String objectName)
    {
      IntPtr handle = CreateEvent(ref securityAttributes, false, false, String.Format(@"{0}\{1}", objectNamePrefix, objectName));

      if(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error() == ErrorAlreadyExists)
        throw new Win32Exception(ErrorAlreadyExists);

      if (handle == IntPtr.Zero)
        throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());

      return new Handle(handle, CloseHandle);
    }
```

Again, ultimately called in the setup of the DbWinMessageSource as follows:

```
  _dbwinBufferReadyEvent = _windowsApi.Basic.CreateGlobalEvent(ref securityAttributes, "DBWIN_BUFFER_READY");
  _dbwinDataReadyEvent = _windowsApi.Basic.CreateGlobalEvent(ref securityAttributes, "DBWIN_DATA_READY");
  _dbwinBufferFile = _windowsApi.Basic.CreateGlobalFileMapping(ref securityAttributes, "DBWIN_BUFFER");
```

I am testing with a simple web application using Log4Net with an OutputDebugString appender configured. When I am running the application via Visual Studio, I capture all Local output as expected. When I move the application in to IIS and configure the code to capture anything in the Global session; I get nothing. I have confirmed that DbgView is capturing the output from IIS as I would expect (so it is definitely something I am doing wrong).

Hopefully that is enough context, but if more information or detail is required; let me know.

Note: Developing on Windows 7 Professional if that makes a difference.

**EDIT**

As pointed out by Tyranid (and Luke), all that should be required is Administrator priviledges, and SE_CREATE_GLOBAL_NAME. I ran a few more tests, and the code setup above is actually capturing *some* Global messages (for instance, during an IISRESET); however the code above is not capturing any data from the Log4Net OutputDebugString appender when an application is running inside of IIS (routed through Local\** during VS sessions). All the Win32 api calls are returning successfully, nor are any errors returned when invoking `Marshal.GetLastWin32Error().` For good measure, I added some code to make sure that the current Windows token has SE_CREATE_GLOBAL_NAME. The roughed in code looked as follows:

```
  using (var identity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent())
  {
    if (identity == null)
      return;

    TokenPrivilege tp;

    tp.Count = 1;
    tp.Luid = 0;
    tp.Attr = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;
    if (!LookupPrivilegeValue(null, SE_CREATE_GLOBAL_NAME, ref tp.Luid))
      throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());

    if (!AdjustTokenPrivileges(identity.Token, false, ref tp, Marshal.SizeOf(tp), IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero))
      throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
  }
```

Any further insight on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What exactly isn't working?  Are the objects successfully created?  Does some specific function fail?

Comment: I tested this using native code and it works fine for me.  The only caveats are that 1) it must be run as administrator and 2) you must enable SeCreateGlobalPrivilege.

Comment: @Luke, as Tyranid pointed out below, I believe my missing piece is the SeCreateGlobalPrivilege. I found the following link that I think will point me in right direction, but haven't had a chance to test it out: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446619(v=VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You sure you are managing to create the section/file mapping object? Yes you need to be admin to do that because creating a file mapping in the global namespace requires SeCreateGlobalPrivilege in your token. Now it is possible you might need to enable that before calling CreateFileMapping but it has been a while since I played with that and don't have my code to hand.

Oh and you really shouldn't specify a NULL DACL, it is just wrong on many levels, I know dbgview does it, but it is just lazy, plus it can break when integrity levels get involved on vista+.

Comment: Interesting... I will explore setting SeCreateGlobalPrivilege  and see if that gets me where I want to be. I will also revisit the NULL DACL; I want to get basic features in place and then I can work on locking everything down once all is good.

Comment: +1 for pointing me in the right direction, but still not quite there... I am not capturing OutputDebugString appender information when running in IIS as I would expect (DbgView is seeing everything). I updated the code above with a snippet to ensure SE_CREATE_GLOBAL_NAME is set, but there is still something else required. No errors are being thrown and as far as all the Win32 API calls go; everything inidicates that it was successful.

Comment: Accepting as answer as this does capture some of my origional global session capture issues; the outstanding issue requires a kernel hook (http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/hooksys.aspx) and technically is a separate issue from what I had origionally posted. Ultimately I ended up going down a separate path.